# Regex to find a string inside a couple of special characters

Tags: regex

Hey guys i am trying to find a pattern in a string let's say this is my string

```
Hello World :this is what i am trying to detect:
```

i am looking for a regex that matches anything that comes between

```
:"STRING":
```

i googled a bit and found some results, but nothing seems to be working. I successfully matched `:test:` but more than one word and it's breaking

this is the best answer i got

```
^[:]\\w+|(?<=\\s)[@#]\\w+
```

Comment: Which language?

Answer (score 3):

You can use that :

```
:(.*?):
```

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/Hc1Uaf/5)

Explanation:

1. `:` looks for the first :
2. `.*?` lazily matches everything until the next :
3. `:` ends the matching

> UPDATE:

If you want go beyond : and look for any special of the following group then you can try this:

```
[:#@]([^:#@]*?)[:#@]
```

[Demo 2](https://regex101.com/r/Hc1Uaf/6)

Answer (score 2):

The trick to matching between characters `X` is to match "everything except `X`" for the body of the message:

```
:[^:]*:
```

The expression means literally this:

- A colon `:`
- Followed by zero or more characters other than colon `[^:]*`
- Another colon `:`

Answer (score 0):

```
([:][A-Za-z0-9]+[:])
```

You can put more character in this range or directly use \s